# How to `git show` on a file that was renamed after specified revision?

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to show the contents of a file in my repository at some point back in time. I use the following command:

```
$ git show "origin/master@{1 year ago}:A/B/C/main.h"
```

However, 1 year ago 'main.h' existed at `X/Y/Z/main.h`. So, if I adjust to this instead:

```
$ git show "origin/master@{1 year ago}:X/Y/Z/main.h"
```

This shows me file content but it's *not* the correct content at that point in time (I haven't verified what version of the content is actually shown, but it seems recent... perhaps the first version of the content *after* the rename). The rename is confusing `git show` and I'm not sure how to make it work.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605416/how-do-i-cat-revisions-of-a-file-following-it-through-renames) which seems to have a similar question. I'd like `git show` to work for this instead of `git log` if possible (since log will only show me the diff with `-p` and I want to see the full content)

Can anyone help me figure out the correct way to do this? It seems that renames throw a big wrench in Git's cogs.

### Update 1

This seems to be an issue with using the `branch@{date}` revision specification. If I grab a SHA1 hash from 1 year ago and run the same command on it, it works fine:

```
$ git show 8f6a0e7:X/Y/Z/main.h
```

So maybe I'm specifying my revision incorrectly?

### Update 2

Apparently the problem is that [revision by date relies on reflogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990484/git-checkout-by-date) which expire and certainly don't go back a year in my case.

Because of this, I am only seeing the file's state as of about 4 weeks ago (since my reflog for origin/master does not go past this).

I originally thought that the rename was causing the issue, but it turns out to be my refspec. So actually my question is wrong: I know how to `git show` on a file at any point in time regardless of rename, however I'd like to be able to do it with a relative time stamp that is calculated by git based on commit timestamps rather than relying on reflog.

Comment: `git log` has a `--follow` option to track renames. Does that work with `git show` as well?

Comment: @chepner It's in the documentation page but using it causes an error: `fatal: --follow requires exactly one pathspec`